# Colocar um iterador em uma tabela em um arquivo .pdf.erb

Tags: html, ruby, contador

Tenho uma tabela onde nela fica uma lista de pessoas queria colocar um contador para ficar um numero do lado de cada item da lista:

tipo assim:

1-Maria.

```
Segue arquivo financial.pdf.erb``<tbody>
        <% @people[:people].each do |person| %>
            <tr>
                <td> <%= person.name %></td>
                <td> <%= person.created_at.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') %></td>
                <td> <%= person.delete_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') unless person.delete_date.nil? %></td>
                <td> <%= person.type_desc %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
```

tem um exemplo em html:

```
                                <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
                                    <td>{{$index + 1}} - {{person.name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{person.created_at.formatDate()}}</td>
                                    <td>{{person.delete_date.formatDate()}}</td>
                                    <td>{{person.type_desc}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta usar o método `#each_with_index` no lugar do `#each` para fazer a iteração.

```
<tbody>
    <% @people[:people].each_with_index do |person, index| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= index + 1 %> - <%= person.name %></td>
            <td> <%= person.created_at.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') %></td>
            <td> <%= person.delete_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') unless person.delete_date.nil? %></td>
            <td> <%= person.type_desc %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: opa jovem obg deu certo! thanks!